# Command line tool to check laptop battery power

Tags: windows, laptop, command-line, power-management, battery

Is there any command line tool to check laptop battery power on Windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/)'s website [**here**](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/battstat_xp.txt) for a potentially useful script you can run from the command line.  The script uses WMIC and works with XP upwards.  Full credit to this guy, looks like a pretty nifty piece of work.

Comment: This works great in Xp.. It calculates runtime left and capacity..works for me!!